# Can't find git plugin in Netbeans 7.0 beta 2

Tags: git, netbeans, beta

Although it's written in several pages of the NetBeans beta 2 release notes (there's even [a tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html)), I downloaded the linux version and I can't find how to install the promised git plugin that will add git support to NetBeans.

Have anyone tried the beta and found the same problem as me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on Netbeans Beta 2 for Linux.

I have done:

1) Go to ***Tools>Plugins*** and you must click on ***Available Plugins*** you will find: 
***Git***.  Check it. Install it.

2) Then, *right click* on your project properties, choose: ***versioning > initialise git repository***

The tutorial that you mention, does it all:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html

Perhaps was a temporary issue?

Comment: Looks like a temporary issue, I've downlodaded it again and now it appears... thanks

Comment: Today 13 July 2011, I've just searched the plugin and it's NOT on my Netbeans 7 list

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the [history of NBGit project](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_plan):

> M4 (7.0 Beta2) **17 February 2011** - IDE integration
>
> - finalize status recognition and caching (DONE)
> - finalize file events handling (DONE)
> - bugtracking integration - commit (DONE), search history,
>
> Covered Use Cases
>
> - Ignore (DONE)
>
> Branching and Merging
>
> - Checkout (DONE)
> - Create Branch (DONE)
> - Switch to Branch (DONE), the same as Checkout
> - maybe also Merge from Branch (DONE)

, you need to:

- grab the sources with the large (Mercurial!) repo http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver (the two Git repo mentionned for the sources are quite obsolete: [myabc/nbgit](https://github.com/myabc/nbgit) and [jonas/nbgit](https://github.com/jonas/nbgit)
- [build and release](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/wiki/HowtoRelease)
- [install](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/wiki/Install)

Comment: Oh, ok thanks. I though that saying IDE integration for 7.0 Beta 2 on February 17th I'd be able to use it now :P